# Logging Madness: AppEngine Standard + Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, logging

I am building what I thought was a vanilla RESTful server. I used Initializr to create the gradle project, added my AppEngine dependencies and away I went. I've been developing and using the project for a while now, but I've run into an issue WRT logging. Basically, everything seems to be cross wired and I can't change any configurations.

From looking at the startup log, I think I can identify AT LEAST three different logging patterns to the console. Adding a logback.xml or logging.properties file does not change anything. I tried a Log4J config as well because, hey why not?

In my gradle file, I have:

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
}
```

and I exclude the jul-to-slf4j in the configurations as:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jul-to-slf4j"
}
```

When the application starts, I get the usual AppEngine message:

```
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'path\to\my\logging.properties'
```

but then I am immediately assaulted by log barf of

```
 2019-03-07 15:59:40.144:WARN:oeja.AnnotationParser:qtp258931371-29: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.MapMakerInternalMap$StrongKeyStrongValueEntry scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///C:/micro_c/workbench/api/build/libs/exploded/workbench-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints-1.9.71.jar!/com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/MapMakerInternalMap$StrongKeyStrongValueEntry.class, jar:file:///C:/micro_c/workbench/api/build/libs/exploded/workbench-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.71.jar!/com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/MapMakerInternalMap$StrongKeyStrongValueEntry.class
```

for just about every dependency.

Additionally, I get some red messages, some white messages. Some look like they're in Log4J format, some look like they are in a java.util.logging format, some are in another undefined format.

I've tried everything I can think of to actually configure this as usual, but it just doesn't seem to be listening to me. I imagine the logbarf about the duplicate classes could be creating some conflict, but I'm just not sure how to proceed.

A couple of notes:

- I'm using IntelliJ
- I'm using the latest GCloud Plugins
- The deployed application works fine
- Logging in the deployed application is also a mess

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your issue so I can troubleshoot it, can you provide more details of the gradle.build file, and versions of everything you are using?

Comment: @alextru, this is the build file. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible but the crazy messages still persist. https://gist.github.com/gte619n/c0019eb252a615da4b02b6159d20a459

Comment: The implementation and configuration lines from your question are different from the ones in the file you sent me. Did these changes have any effect on the logs?

Comment: @alextu, still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you please describe step by step exactly how you build and run in local?

Comment: @alextu, I've created a new project and am still getting the same funny logging errors. I've setup the project using grade, then to deploy into AppEngine local using the Google Cloud Tool plugins. I just run it through the IDE currently.

Comment: I suggest you replicate in your system any of the examples in the GCP docs, and add one by one the changes needed until you get what you currently have.